# Vaadin Accordion in Panel should scroll to see contents

Tags: java, accordion, panel, vaadin

I got a `Accordion` embedded into a normal `Panel`. The `Accordion` size is half the current screen size.

Now if I add content (tab) to the `Accordion`, the `Accordion` itself contains a caption followed by the content and I can see the content clearly.

If I add more than, say about 30 tabs, I can only see the caption, cause it takes also space from the `Accordion`.

Now my question is, how can I set the tabs content size, that I always can see the content or is it possible to show the scrollbar of the underlying `Panel`, cause it is not showing up.

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of many tabs added to the accordion:

[image]
I can not scroll an if I click onto an item, it won't expand.

Comment: Can you post a printscreen for the 30-tabs version?

Comment: seems to be the wrong widget for 30 tabs...

Comment: @AndréSchild Added a screenshot.

Comment: check out the sampler: http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/structure/accordion; same issue, maybe open a bug ticket. But I still think that accordions are not intended to handle a lot of tabs in a small place, maybe a tabsheet or a normal list with a implemented details-view is a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a TabSheet. It is not the best solution, but okay for me. Here is the reported bug link: https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/18219